# How does warm_start option in scikit-learn work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to train a network on a dataset and then continue training on further data. This should be possible with the "warm_start" option in scikit-learn. As far as I know it should set the weights to zero with every initialization and in case of several calls to fit use the weights of the previous fit call as starting point for the next fit if the warm_start parameter is set to True.

However, comparing the two options (warm_start = True/False) in practice yields identical results for weights and consequently for predictions.
The only difference seems to be, that weights are updated retrospectively if assigned to variables in between if warm_start = True.

The following code illustrates this with a simple scikit-learn dataset and the ElasticNet as model. weights_1 changes values after the second fit such that weights_1 == weights_2 for warm_start = True (as described above), whereas weights_1 keeps the values of the first fit in case of warm_start = False (set warm_start to False in a second run for comparison).

Am I using the warm_start parameter incorrectly or otherwise: what is its application, if the results do not depend on whether it is used or not?

In case the warm_start is not suitable for my purpose at all, would it be somehow possible to just pass weights from a previous fit into a model? I couldn't find any parameter to set initial coefficients for the models that are of interest for me (ElasticNet and MLPRegressor).

```
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

X_1, X_2, y_1, y_2 = X[:len(X)/2], X[len(X)/2:], y[:len(y)/2], y[len(y)/2:]

model_1 = linear_model.ElasticNet(alpha = 0.01, warm_start=True)
in_weights = model_1.coef_
print 'Initialization : \nin_weights', in_weights
model_1.fit(X_1, y_1)
weights_1 = model_1.coef_
print '\nFirst fit:\n in_weights', in_weights, '\n \nweights_1 \n', weights_1
model_1.fit(X_2, y_2)
weights_2 = model_1.coef_
print '\n Second Fit: \nin_weights \n', in_weights, '\n \nweights_1 \n', weights_1, '\n \nweights_2 \n', weights_2
```

Comment: Alright. I have received a response and I have falsely parsed the operator precedence. To my concern then, the `warm_start` parameter works as intended as it passes the `coef_` variable from the precedent fit to the next one as stated in *coordinate_descent.py*. You could debug the script if you wanted :). To sum, when you type `warm_start = True`, it actually passes `coef_` from the last fit the next one and does not provoke `coef_ = np.zeros((n_targets, n_features), ...)`.

Comment: For me too, neither warm_start nor partial_fit making the data to add up incrementally to the already trained model as tried here: https://ideone.com/v5yaRs. I have to give all my lables before the first initial_fit() which seems like it is same as fit().